# Django in Subdirectory - Success URL Redirect

Tags: django

I have a url `http://localhost/project_name/`. My `ListView` is working prefectly fine as url `http://localhost/project_name/company/`. But when i am adding a company using `CreateView` then it is redirecting me to `http://localhost/company/` which is saying Page Not Found.

```
class CompanyListView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'company/company.html'
    queryset = Company.objects.all()
    context_object_name = 'companies'
    paginate_by = 10

    def get_queryset(self):
        return ( 
            self.queryset.exclude(id=1)
            .exclude(company_is_deleted=True)
            .annotate(number_of_company_users=Count('userprofile'))
        )


class CompanyCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.CreateView):
    model = Company
    template_name = 'company/company_form.html'
    fields = ['company_name', 'company_description', 'company_email', 
    'company_website', 'company_address', 'company_phone', 'company_status', 
    'company_monthly_payment', 'company_logo']

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('superadmin_company')
```

project_name/urls.py

```
path('company/', include(company_urls)),
```

apps/company/urls.py

```
path('', views.CompanyListView.as_view(), name='superadmin_company'),
path('add', views.CompanyCreateView.as_view(), name='superadmin_company_create'),
```

How can i redirect using `get_succes_url()` with project_name in url as `http://localhost/project_name/company/` after adding the data using `CreateView`

Comment: `http://localhost/project_name/` is it the path where the application is deployed? I mean is it deployed in sub path?

Comment: yes it is subdirectory. those view who don't have successurl are working

Comment: What makes you think you need to do anything? This should just work. What happens when you try it?

Comment: @DanielRoseman it is not append my sub_path in my url after after success_url

Comment: You need to show some details of how you configured your server to serve Django at that subpath.

Comment: @DanielRoseman how can i do it sir

Comment: You *post some details*.

Comment: @DanielRoseman It just a issue of `get_success_url()`

Comment: **No it isn't**. Show the details of how you configured your server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are deploying your application in subpath, then you need to define [FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#force-script-name) in your settings. So you can update the settings like this:

```
FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME = "/project_name"
```

Comment: Actually you shouldn't need to, although it might fix this. In most configurations Django picks up the value of SCRIPT_NAME automatically.